# How to allow special customers to bypass the website .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, security

I have a strict .htaccess file, that blocks countries like Russia or China.
Some of my clients, may - on occasion - travel to such countries.

What is the easiest/safest way to just let someone bypass the .htaccess rules?

Clients need to access sections of the website without logging in.

It is not known what country the client will be accessing from nor when the client will be accessing.

The only constant is the specific URL's available, some of which are global.

What we may sometimes know is - when a client complains they can not access.

No sure the route to go here.
To force clients to log in?
But then how do they access the log in page from blocked countries?
It is a real conundrum for me.

Current .htaccess:

```
order allow,deny
# Cambodia (KH)
deny from ###.###.###.#/## 
deny from ... etc...

allow from all
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Show your current htaccess file

Comment: This depends on how you want to identify those clients you want to grant access to. And what technical possibilities you have, which depends on how you operate that site. You told us nothing into that direction which is why your question is far too generic, too vague to be answered.

Comment: "without logging in" - If clients don't "log in" (or authenticate in some way), how do you differentiate a "client" from joe public? (Curious what service you are providing?) The "clients" could use a VPN to circumvent the IP restriction, but so could _anyone_ use a VPN for the same purpose. "bypass the .htaccess rules" - a little misleading... you want to bypass the IP restriction, which you happen to have implemented in `.htaccess`. You certainly don't want to bypass `.htaccess` entirely as that will break your site. How many "clients" does this affect?

Comment: Sounds like you are as mystified as me. I have no idea how to handle this problem. It is a monitoring service, where customers travel, but check in to the service to see what's going on. Some customers may travel to these banned countries - we have no way of knowing which customers may do this. A part of me says - well - if they have this specific link - maybe let them in. Not sure if there is a way to do that in .htaccess